# Excel - finding optimum amount to contain X elements

Tags: excel

Sorry about the title - a tough one to explain. I have the following in Excel

```
Col A | Col B | Col C
---------------------
244   | 2     | 4 -> wrong
244   | 1000  | 4 -> wrong
244   | 0     | 5 -> right
245   | 500   | 5 -> right
247   | 500   | 5 -> right
```

So I want to see what is the minimum amount of times I can fit in the number 49 into column A (the result goes into C) without wasting any space (using col B as extra)

So let's take the first row for example

244 is one less than 49 x 5. So 49 goes into 244, four times (plus the remainder. We can't have decimals, we need whole numbers. However we have space for one more number. We can therefore borrow 1 from Col B so we can actually have 5 in Col C.

Likewise for the second row.

For the 3rd, row, since we will need 5 anyway, we just accept this.

Does this make any sense at all? It's a tough one to explain

Comment: To answer that last question, hum, not really? It would be helpful to give us starting data, *then* expected output (in a separate table), *then* a clarification on "...what is the minimum amount of times I can fit in the number 49 into column A" -- surely you mean maximum (the minimum would be `0`) and do you mean the entire column or each individual cell?

Comment: If you're 'borrowing' from B, why not borrow 47 from the 500 in the last row to make 6?  Is there a limit to what can be borrowed, or a minimum remainder to ignore borrowing?